# Why I can't use Page Factory in my TestNg class

Tags: testng, page-factory

I tried to use `@FindBy` in my code but it's not working

This is PageObjectModel class

```
package Support;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;

public class LoginPom {

    WebDriver driver;

    public LoginPom(WebDriver driver) {

        this.driver=driver;
    }

    @FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using="//*[@id=\"input-email\"]")
    WebElement txtEmail;

    @FindBy(xpath="//*[@id=\"input-password\"]")
    WebElement txtPassword;

    @FindBy(xpath="//*[@id=\"content\"]/div/div[2]/div/form/input")
    WebElement submitLogin;

public void loginAccount(String email,String password) {

        txtEmail.sendKeys(email);

        txtPassword.sendKeys(password);

        submitLogin.click();
        }
}
```

And this is TestNG class

```
package Support;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;

public class TestDemoPage {

      WebDriver driver;

  @Test()
  public void TestCase_1() {

     LoginPom loginPom=PageFactory.initElements(driver,LoginPom.class);

      loginPom.loginAccount("user@mail.com", "password");

  }


  @BeforeMethod
  public void openBrowser() {
      String exePath="C:\\chromedriver.exe";

      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",exePath);

      driver= new ChromeDriver();

      driver.manage().window().maximize();

      driver.get("https://demo.opencart.com/index.php?route=account/login");  
  }
}
```

And the exception I'm getting is

```
FAILED: TestCase_1
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="input-email"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528161 (5b82f2d2aae0ca24b877009200ced9065a772e73),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:33:08.638Z'
System info: host: 'LIN20000762', ip: '10.77.250.162', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.35.528161 (5b82f2d2aae0ca..., userDataDir: C:\Users\raguts\AppData\Loc...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: , unhandledPromptBehavior: , version: 65.0.3325.181, webStorageEnabled: true}
Session ID: 5886cb0af3672fa6dcf79ee3019caf3e
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//*[@id="input-email"]}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:545)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:319)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:421)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:361)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:311)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:69)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:38)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8.sendKeys(Unknown Source)
    at Support.SupportLoginPageObjectModel.loginAccount(SupportLoginPageObjectModel.java:34)
    at Support.SupportTestDemoPage.TestCase_1(SupportTestDemoPage.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:580)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:716)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:988)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Thanks, for help me to resolve this problem and use PageFactory properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend invoking the page factory within the page object itself (or ideally create a base class and do it there):

```
public LoginPom(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver=driver;
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}
```

and then initialize your test object as:

```
LoginPom loginPom = new LoginPom(driver);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add abstract class that contains driver, waiter declarations and invoke initializers. 
In the the waiter (fluent wait) add the pagefactory.initelements().
Let all POMs extend above abstract class to get same driver.